# Using fit with nodeparts

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, border

I'm trying to fit the nodes `one` and `two` belonging to a parted node, in order to encapsulate them inside a rectangle with a different color:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (qs) [draw,font=\tiny,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=3,
        text centered,
        align=center,
        ] at (-2.3,0) {%
            \nodepart{one} one
            \nodepart{two} two
            \nodepart{three} three
        };
        
        \node[fit=(qs.one above left)(qs.two),rectangle,draw=red,line width=1mm] {};
        \node[fit=(qs.one north west)(qs.two),rectangle,draw=red,line width=1mm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way, it recognizes neither `above left` nor `north west`. What is the best solution to draw this border with the correct coordinates?

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `one' (in 'one above
> left'). ...qs.two),rectangle,draw=red,line width=1mm]
>
> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `one' (in 'one north west').
> ...qs.two),rectangle,draw=red,line width=1mm]

Comment: multi part node doesn't have anchor `.one north west` ... instead it  you should use `.north west`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect, that you looking for

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                shapes,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
F/.style = {draw=red, line width=1mm, inner sep=0mm}
                        ]
\node (qs) [draw,font=\tiny,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=3,
            text centered,
            align=center] at (-2.3,0) {%
    \nodepart{one} one
    \nodepart{two} two
    \nodepart{three} three
};

\node[F, fit=(qs.north west) (qs.two split east)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Edit:* now images is corrected as requested in comment.

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer to group `one` and `two` inside a same box/frames, and not to split such box into two parts. I'm doing this because in my original example boxes are already colored, and box/frames only hilights the steps of my algorithm.

Comment: @jackb, answer is corrected.